# Shifting bits and bytes to create encryption

Tags: c, encryption

I'm writing a program that encrypts based on bit/byte shifts. This program currently takes in a file, displays the contents, then displays the hex values.

To encrypt the file I am suppose to perform bit/byte shifts.  However, I loaded the file into an array and performed shifts through the use of temp swaps.  I'm pretty sure the outcome is the same, but I wanted to implement this with the proper bit shifts.

To produce the same results, do I just say load[x>>3] to shift the bits?  I'm getting terrible results attempting to implement this.

Below is the entire block of code with a sample output at the end.  Thanks in advance to everyone for your time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {


FILE *fp;
char ch;
char load[100];
int count1 = 0;
int count2 = 0;
int i = 0; 

fp = fopen("load.txt", "r");

if (fp == NULL)
{
    perror("Exiting, an error occured while opening\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
    printf("%c", ch);
    ++count1;
}

fclose(fp);


fp = fopen("load.txt", "r");

if (fp == NULL)
{
    perror("Exiting, an error occured while opening\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

printf("\n\n");

while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
    printf("%x ", ch);
    ++count2;
}

fclose(fp);

printf("\n\n");

printf("Count1: %d, Count2: %d \n", count1, count2);    

printf("\n\n");

fp = fopen("load.txt", "r");

if (fp == NULL)
{
    perror("Exiting, an error occured while opening\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

i = 0;

while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
    load[i++] = ch;

}

load[i] = 0;        

fclose(fp);

 // for(i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
 // {

 //     printf("%s", load);
 // }

printf("\n\n");

for(i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
{
    printf("%x ", load[i]);
}   

 // printf("\n index i: %c\n", load[0]);

     //shift bytes

char temp, temp2, temp3, temp4;

temp = load[7];
load[7] = load[11];
load[11] = temp;

temp2 = load[8];
load[8] = load[12];
load[12] = temp2;

temp3 = load[9];
load[9] = load[13];
load[13] = temp3;

temp4 = load[10];
load[10] = load[14];
load[14] = temp4;

printf("\n\n");

for(i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
{
    printf("%x ", load[i]);
}   

printf("\nAfter byte shift: \n %s", load);
     //shift bites
temp = load[6];
load[6] = load[4];
load[4] = temp; 

temp2 = load[5];
load[5] = load[3];
load[3] = temp2;

printf("\nAfter bit shift: \n %s", load);

printf("\n\n");

for(i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
{
    printf("%x ", load[i]);
}   



printf("\n\n");
return 0;
}
```

The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.

54 68 65 20 71 75 69 63 6b 20 62 72 6f 77 6e 20 66 6f 78 20 6a 75 6d 70 65 64 20 6f 76 65 72 20 74 68 65 20 6c 61 7a 79 20 64 6f 67 2e a

Count1: 46, Count2: 46

54 68 65 20 71 75 69 63 6b 20 62 72 6f 77 6e 20 66 6f 78 20 6a 75 6d 70 65 64 20 6f 76 65 72 20 74 68 65 20 6c 61 7a 79 20 64 6f 67 2e a 0 0 0 0

54 68 65 20 71 75 69 72 6f 77 6e 63 6b 20 62 20 66 6f 78 20 6a 75 6d 70 65 64 20 6f 76 65 72 20 74 68 65 20 6c 61 7a 79 20 64 6f 67 2e a 0 0 0 0

After byte shift: 
 The quirownck b fox jumped over the lazy dog.

After bit shift: 
 Theui qrownck b fox jumped over the lazy dog.

54 68 65 75 69 20 71 72 6f 77 6e 63 6b 20 62 20 66 6f 78 20 6a 75 6d 70 65 64 20 6f 76 65 72 20 74 68 65 20 6c 61 7a 79 20 64 6f 67 2e a 0 0 0 0

Comment: I cant understand what is your problem

Comment: I am a little confused as to what you are trying to accomplish.  Your code prints "After bit shift:", but I do not see where you are doing any bit shifts in the code.  Are you asking us how you are supposed to accomplish the bit shifts?

Comment: Yes. Currently I'm using temp to swap values in an array, but I want to perform the bit shift instead.  Would load[i>>4] perform a bit shift?

Comment: Small stuff not shift related: 1)  `int ch;`, not `char ch` 2) After finding file char count, use `char load[count2];` instead of `char load[100];` 3) `for(i = 0; i < 50; ++i)` --> `for(i = 0; i < count2; ++i)`

Comment: `load[i] >>= 3`  Will shift `load[i]` 3 bits to the right (MSBits moving toward LSBits).  Those 3 will be lost.  Say you want to shift 3 bits for all `load[]`, one into its neighbor in a circle: `unsigned char load[count2]; unsigned acc = load[count2-1] & 7; for (i = 0; i < count2; ++i) { acc <<= 8; acc |= load[i]; load[i] = acc >> 3; }` or something like that.  Perhaps someone will post a more clear example.